# REST API AWS cloud using java

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am new to **AWS** , want to develop a cloud ready java application **REST API**.

The application will hit the **MySQL** database and produce output as **JSON** after querying the database.

`IP:port/application?q=<query>` response is JSON.

How to achieve it ? the data in **MySQL** is mostly static **100MB** data but used very frequently.

Comment: This question is not properly asked.  Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very straight forward. if you already have same application running in your local system , then you can just move it to AWS , using below steps :-

1. spin up new ec2 instance, if you are using a free-tier then you can spin up lots of AWS resources for free , more information on https://aws.amazon.com/free/ .
2. install all the required s/w like Java, maven , tomcat and mysql and whatever your application is using on Ec2 instance . you can even have a free RDS (Database) instance in free tier which you can use for your application , instead of having the database installed locally on your application server.
3. while creating the ec2 server , configure instance security group properly for ex 8080 for http and 22 for SSH , 3306 for mysql etc. (This is important and try to be as restrtict as possible to make it safe from hackers).
4. build and deploy your application and access it using any REST client , by giving instance ip and application port number.

There are several resources online for AWS , you can refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oS7VYX7LXUo which talks about deploying a java application to AWS.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying Java apps (for example, a Spring BOOT APP) that interacts with the Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) to the cloud is easy when using Elastic Beanstalk. An example of a Spring Boot database application that queries data from MySQL running on the cloud is documented here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_secure_spring_app