# How to build a netbean project on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, build, terminal

I created a java web project on netbean. it is working fine on local machine. I want to build the same java project on aws instance without netbean and also deploy the war file over there. 
Can any one tell the process how to build the java project on aws instance. 
All the files are uploaded using subversion on aws instance.

Comment: Could you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235012/rest-api-aws-cloud-using-java/41235422#41235422 , it has most of the things which you need.

Comment: Hi amit thanks for reference, but you are not getting my point. i want to build whole application online not locally. i want to upload files build there (for war file) and deploy there.