# Deploying a REST API to AWS

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, netbeans

I am making a distributed system as a school project and I need to have a REST service. This will be a simple service with a login/register function and some information transfer.

I have made the REST API in Java in NetBeans. It works fine locally, but I am having difficulties to put it on my AWS server. I have no experience with servers, so I don't really know how it works. I thought that it should easy to get the service up and running on a server.

So far I have used [this](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-create-restful-webservice-in-java-part-2/) guide for the REST and tried to deploy the war-file with Elastic Beanstalk.

My Java code:

ApplicationConfig.java

```
package dk.dtu.ds.login;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("CoL")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(dk.dtu.ds.login.Login.class);
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
package dk.dtu.ds.login;

import cleanoutloudserver.ICleanOutLoud;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

@Path("login")
public class Login {
    // HTTP Get Method

    @GET
    @Path("dologin")
    // Produces JSON as response
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    // Query parameters are parameters: http://localhost/colrest/CoL/login/dologin?username=s150157&password=1234
    public String doLogin(@QueryParam("username") String uname, @QueryParam("password") String pwd) throws MalformedURLException, Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://ec2-52-43-233-138.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3769/col?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName("http://cleanoutloudserver/", "CleanOutLoudImplService");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        ICleanOutLoud col = service.getPort(ICleanOutLoud.class);

        String token = col.login(uname, pwd);

            token = Utility.constructJSON(token);
            System.out.println("\nChecking credentials = true\n");
        return token;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>RESTWebApp</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>dk.dtu.ds.login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I then try to open the [path](http://sample-env.dj8s8m3jxe.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/colrest/CoL/login/dologin?username=s150157&password=1234) for the service, I get a blank page. My Chrome console says "GET (link) 404 (Not Found)"

Since I am not that familiar with HTTP and servers, I don't know what to do.
Isn't there an easy way to deploy a simple REST service with AWS or have I done something wrong?

I have really tried to search google to find help, but there has been no success so far.

Comment: You may need to setup the required access via IAM policy.

Comment: How did you package and test the application locally?  You'll need extra libraries to run on the AWS ElasticBeanstalk Tomcat instance type but they are the same ones you'd need on a local Tomcat.

Comment: try follow the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235012/rest-api-aws-cloud-using-java/41235422#41235422 , let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like i got too confused by all the guides out there.
I found an easy solution and installed Tomcat on the EC2 instance, so I didn't even need to use Beanstalk.

All I did was following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide and uploaded the war-file in the Web Application Manager and now it works fine.

Thanks for the comments they helped me on the way to find a solution.